# arraycollection unique var

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

How do I create a new arraycollection that can generate a unique variable name?

Like:

```
AC+nu as in AC1:ArrayCollection
AC+nu as in AC2:ArrayCollection
AC+nu as in AC3:ArrayCollection
AC+nu as in AC4:ArrayCollection
nu++;
```

Comment: So you want this to be done at run time right? Perhaps if you tell us why you want to do this, maybe we can come up with a solution :)

Comment: I have multiple datagrid, if I correct, the datagrid can only accept AC, so if I using one AC, whether changes made to AC will affected other datagrid using the same AC, I think would having unique AC for each datagrid is correct?

Comment: I am not sure whether a DataGrid can only accept AC or not. I thought it could accept XML as well. That issue aside, yes, you will need a unique AC for each datagrid. Are you populating the grids at runtime in a loop? Or are you calling them one by one?

Comment: Calling them one by one.

Comment: Don't ask a technical question like 'how do I do x in code'.  Instead ask the problem you're having 'I'm trying to do X, how do I do it?'  I still don't get why you need more than one ArrayCollection if you're showing the same data in both DataGrids.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
var ac1:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(sourceArrayCollection.list);
var ac2:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(sourceArrayCollection.list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider a super ArrayCollection to store all ArrayCollection you have. The ideal is like a two dimensional array.

```
            var superDataCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            var dc:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            var di:Object = new Object();
            di.label1 = "Test";
            di.label2 = "Test2";
            dc.addItem(di);
            superDataCollection.addItem(dc);
            myDG.dataProvider = superDataCollection[0];
```